# Changing click behaviour

Tags: windows-phone-7

When a Button having Content / Text 'ClickMe' is clicked, 'ClickMe' text is automatically arranged to foreground of the button. 
But when user clicks the button having image on its background, background image becomes invisible & the foreground of button looks fully white.
Can we see the image on foreground instead of white color.

Is there any chance to change the foreground effect of the button when user clicks on button?

My Code "Button Height="128" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,138,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" BorderThickness="1">

"Button.Background>

ImageBrush ImageSource="/WinApp;component/Icons/camerabtn.png" />

/Button.Background>

/Button>"

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: It might help us to help you if you can post some repro code we can run to see the sparkling effect you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to change the style of the button.

Easiest way to do that is in Expression Blend.

See this answer:
[Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

As Mick suggests, it would help to see some code for what you're trying to do, however, it sounds like you may have a change in a value (such as margin) in the Normal and Pressed states of the button resulting in the behavior you are seeing.