# WP7 How do I change the image of a button when clicked

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, button

Right now I have a grid of six buttons, all with different images inside them.  I have another set of six images, that are the original just with a gray tint to represent you selecting it.  How do I change the image to the button to the new "selected image" when I select the button.

I am assuming you do it in the method:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to put inside here.  Normally I would think it would be something like:

```
button1.image = "image path";
```

However when making a WP7 application you cannot use the image keyword.  Any advice on how to change the image of a button when clicked?

Answer (score 3):

Write where you want to change the image

```
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/YourImage.png", 
                                            UriKind.Relative));
btn.Background = brush;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Silverlight (upon which the Windows Phone 7 framework is built) the `Button` control does not have an `Image` property. I presume that you have created your original buttons by placing an `Image` element as the child of the `Button`. On the assumption that you want the same behavior for a whole set of buttons, then it might make sense to use visual states instead. You coudl achieve a consistent look-and-feel by changing the opacity of the `ContentPresenter`, e.g. An `Opacity` of 0.75 for the "Normal" state and and `Opacity` of 1.0 for the "Selected" state.

Determing which button is the selected one would be the trickier part, but if you wrap your buttons in a `ListBox` then you can use the "Selected" visual state in the `ItemContainerStyle`.

If you want to continue with the approach that you've already taken, then given that you know that the content of the button is an `Image`, you could do something like the following:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button source = (Button)sender;
    Image content = source.Content as Image;
    if (null != content)
    {
        content.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image path"));
    }
}
```

In this approach you would, of course, also need to handle reverting the other buttons back to their "Normal" state, which the `ListBox` approach would handle for you.

Comment: The listBox idea makes sense and would be very helpful, however i have six buttons that are arranged in a 2x3 grid, so I can't think of a way that the listBox would work. When I tried the block of code you suggested I got an error using the Bitmap Image, it said that it didn't exist in the namespace. Should I be using a specific namespace?

Comment: The 2x3 grid effect can be implemented in a `ListBox` by specifying a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`, as shown in this blog post: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth. The `BitmapImage` class is in the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace, so you'll need to add a `using` statement for that namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=VS.95).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a really good learning exercise - you'll learn lots about Silverlight by experimenting like this.

In addition to manually adjusting the image to match the button press state, I believe you can also achieve the effect you are looking for - that the button image becomes "gray" when pressed - you can do this using "Styles" and using "Behaviors". Take a look at posts like:

- http://mstechno.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/silverlight-3-how-to-customize-a-button-with-expression-blend-3/
- [Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)

Some of the XAML in this might look daunting - and using Expression Blend takes some time to get used to - but you will get there. Good luck!