# Set StoryBoard target in datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, datatemplate, storyboard

I would like to use a StoryBoard to show an image with plane projection animation when I click on a button.

That works when I try it on a only one instance.

But in my silverlight page (windows phone 7), I use data template to repeat it from a collection of objects.

And here, it doesn't work.

Here is the .xaml of the data template :

```
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="MyDt">
                                <Button Tag="{Binding iId}" BorderThickness="0" Click="buttonClick" Width="456" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                                    <Image x:Name="MyImg" Source="Images/image.png" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <Image.Projection>
                                            <PlaneProjection/>
                                        </Image.Projection>
                                    </Image>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
```

Here is the .xaml of the storyboard (in phone page resources) :

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="storyboardShowImage">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Here is the .cs of click event on the button :

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Get image object from x:Name */
        Image img;
        img = GetChildImage((DependencyObject)sender, "MyImg");
        /* Launch storyboard on img object */
        ((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)storyboardShowImage.Children[0]).SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, img.Name);
        storyboardShowImage.Begin();
    }
```

But I get error :

```
Cannot resolve TargetName MyImg.
```

I think it's because there is multiple Image objects with x:Name "MyImg", but I don't know how to set storyboard target on the correct image in my data template.

Answer (score 3):

It can't resolve to that name because that name is local to the DataTemplate. You could either move the Storyboard within the DataTemplate so that it can be applied to the image in each instance and use VisualStateManager to start the animation in the Pressed state, or you could create the Storybaord in code and set the target accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm newbie and don't really know how to use StoryBoard in DataTemplate and start it with VisualStateManager. Have you got a sample ? a link ?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click You just need to make your changes in the Pressed state, then apply the Button style to the Button in your DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanks for link. I try to use VisualState to change launch storyboard, but I would like to launch it when button is clicked, and when I use Expression Blend I only see my button visula stats : "Normal", "MouseOver", "Pressed", "Disabled"

Comment: Yes, true but on the phone there's very little difference between Pressed and Click :)