# Imagebutton change source property

Tags: windows-phone-7, custom-controls, custom-attributes

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have a custom button with an image inside. This is its XAML code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Image Margin="45,8,35,8" Source="Images/Delete.png"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How can I change Image Source property programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

To change the source of an image you need to make a new bitmap of your asset and set it as a souce

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/foo.png", UriKind.Relative));

imageButton.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

**but** I guess you would like to have a button that change its background if is clicked. You need to redefine Visual States of the button. Here is an example:

[Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)