# How to change image source in WP8 using C#?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have an Image object created in XAML in my Windows Phone 8 project. I'd like to change the Source property in C#. How would I go about doing that? I've followed the code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770527/imagebutton-change-source-property but had no success. BitmapImage does not seem to be valid for Windows Phone 8. Does anyone know the correct way to change image sources in C# for WP8? Thank you.

Comment: According to documentation, there is BitmapImage class in Windows Phone 8 SDK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms619218(v=vs.105).aspx  So it is not clear why you can't use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "had no success"? Compiler error, runtime error, what?

Comment: Thank you for that link ie. It turns out I had to import the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace, I wrongly assumed it would be available already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution ended up being something simple. I just needed to import the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace. I added

> using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

to the top of my file, which fixed the problem.