# Button Skinning in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a derived button class which contains a couple ImageSource members for the Normal and Pressed states. I need to be able to change the image to the Pressed image whenever the user presses the button.

Looking around I've noticed that you can use VisualStateManager in xaml to specify the bitmaps to use for each state. [Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)

Now this is all fine and dandy, but I need to be able to do the same thing dynamically rather than at design time. Is there a way to do this in code?

Or can I override some event handler and set the background manually? Seems that there are no event handler to trap this and it's a no-no from what I read...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:-

In the ManipulationStarted event handler you can change the image-source to the pressed image.

In ManipulationDelta event handler check if the button is not pressed then change the image to the normal one.

Finally in ManipulationCompleted event handler change the image to the normal one.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This doesn't work... My ManipulationCompleted event handler is not called when I click the button. No can I seem to trap a Click handler.

Comment: Ok, I did managed to get this to work! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. What I did was use a Panel as the base class for the custom control, and then place an Image control on top of it. The ManipulatedXxx events did not work correctly on a Button, and did not work at all on the Panel. But they worked great on the Image! So I used those to change the image source of the Image to the correct image based on the state. Thanks! (I guess I could have derived directly from Image, but I need other controls in there too...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting images for each state as properties in your control?

Comment: create your own properties in your derived control and bind these to the image properties for the different states.

Comment: I have properties of type ImageSource in my control. How do I bind them so that it switches to my pressed ImageSource when appropriate? Is this something similar to what is done here? http://www.silvergeek.net/windows-phone-7/imagebutton-control-for-win-phone-7/