# Why is this button behaviour different in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Two buttons:

```
    <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,92,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
```

Self explanatory code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Color c = ((SolidColorBrush)((Button)sender).Background).Color;

        if (c == Colors.Red)
        {
            c = Colors.Green;
        }
        else if (c == Colors.Green)
        {
            c = Colors.Blue;
        }
        else if (c == Colors.Blue)
        {
            c = Colors.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            c = Colors.Yellow;
        }

        ((Button)sender).Background = new SolidColorBrush(c);
        button2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(c);
    }
```

In an ordinary Silverlight app everthing works exactly as expected.  However, in Windows Phone 7 the exact same code behaves as follows:

button1 does not change color (it just stays red)
button2 does change color unless I click it in which case it no longer changes color when I click button1 (i.e. its color is now stuck as well)

clue enyone?

Comment: was here many times. Use visual state http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do the trick:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
var brush = ((SolidColorBrush)btn.Background);

if (brush.Color == Colors.Red)
    brush.Color = Colors.Green;
else if (brush.Color == Colors.Green)
    brush.Color = Colors.Blue;
else if (brush.Color == Colors.Blue)
    brush.Color = Colors.Red;
else
    brush.Color = Colors.Yellow;

btn.Background = brush;
button2.Background = brush;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to set the background of the Button. This will run the Background code on the Button's thread (To my understanding at least)

```
        button2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
             button2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(c);
        });
```

I'm not sure if this would fix anything, but it's worth a try.

-Woody

Comment: Well then I've got nothing. Sorry

Comment: For why this doesn't work see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx