# Windows Phone: How to disable button background when is pressed programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a button in my windows phone app. When I am pressing it, its background color turns to yellow. How can I disable this feature, then instead of having a yellow color I want to see no change.

```
enter code here

 Button btn = new Button();
```

thanks,Bahador

Comment: do you use yellow color theme on your phone? You need just edit button style.

Comment: how can I change the style programmatically?

Comment: I'd use an image instead of a button, just set set the manipulation started event to trigger a change in the source of the image, and the manipulation ended to change it back to make it look like a button, you could also add a tilt effect. Oh and of course add the tap event to apply your logic

Comment: In addition if you use an image you can change the shape, size, look, of the "button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use Blend to edit the pressed state or override the theme accent brushes

Comment: I am creating a button programmatically. can I still use blend?  How should I override the accent brush ? can yous show me a code?

Comment: Certainly. Try right clicking on the page in the solution Explorer and select "Open in Blend".

Alternately check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click

See how they have set the style in resources and set it on the button...just search for "Cyan" and set it to whatever color you want!

Please mark as answer if this helped!