# disable the background button c# in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background

I am developping a windows phone 8 application and I need to disable the background button when webservice is loading.
is there any capability to disable the background button using c# in windows phone 8 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone: How to disable button background when is pressed programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965926/windows-phone-how-to-disable-button-background-when-is-pressed-programmatically)

Comment: this is not what I want .I mean the start menu that let app got to background(how I can disable it)

Answer (score 0):

Put this `LoadCompleted="htmlLoadCompleted"` in your Web Service. And create Button like my below code.

```
<Button x:Name="CoverImage" Content="Loading..." Opacity="0.5" />
```

C# Code:

```
private void htmlLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.CoverImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable button by decreasing opacity of that button to 0.0 & after completion of your web service call increase opacity to 1.0 to visible.

If you want that user can not interact with the screen then it is better to use progress overlay of coding4fun toolkit.

Just write below code in XAML file before last grid ends.

```
<Code4funToolkit:ProgressOverlay  Name="progressOverlay" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtprogressbar"  Text="Loading functionality" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"  TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
            <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  IsIndeterminate="True"  Visibility="Visible"  Foreground="White" Height="15"  x:Name="standardProgressBar"  Width="464" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Code4funToolkit:ProgressOverlay>
```

When you want to restrict user to interact just write below code.

```
progressOverlay.Show();
```

To disable overlay write

```
progressOverlay.Hide();
```

Suggestion :- Progress overlay of coding4fun toolkit is more feasible option when you are dealing with web services & its response.