# Custom back button - back glyph and circle missing

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

After editing a copy of the back button, I noticed that the back glyph and the circle are not appearing (a rectangle appears instead). How can I change the shape to a circle and show the back glyph? Please do not refer to `StandardStyles.xaml`.

```
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNavy" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000099"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000099"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#000099"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...May be this could work.

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonGlyph">&#xE071;</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonSnappedGlyph">&#xE0BA;</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonGlyph">&#xE071;</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonSnappedGlyph">&#xE0C4;</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>    



<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="36,0,36,36"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid Margin="-1,-16,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0A6;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using "Ellipse" shape you can design circular back button and visit this link also [Buttons styled to look like app bar buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086694/buttons-styled-to-look-like-app-bar-buttons)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNavy" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000099"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000099"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Ui Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#000099"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="Border" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="3" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol" Content="&#xE112;" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleNavy}" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2"></Button>
</Grid>
```

[image]